# Flutter App Showing Grey Screen when internet is off(in debug apk)

Tags: flutter, widget, azure-devops-rest-api

My Flutter App (on installing the build apk) is showing this grey screen when fetching data from api and I have assigned some different widget when it encounters empty data from api and it works only in debug mode but when I build the APK of the app It is showing the below screen.

Also, when I enter some data the screen shows the data plus the grey screen in the remaining area.

But when I log out and then log in the issue disappears, I am talking about release mode only because in debug mode the error never appeared.

I tried changing the channel using flutter channel master and then flutter upgrade but for some reason that completely crashed my flutter SDK and dart SDK and I had to download flutter SDK again, that's a story for some other day, but this is the issue in hand.

What It Should Show: List of restaurants and its details [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tZ0Qe.png).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

-> This issue comes when there is null value in data in android it show red screen and in iOS its shows gray screen

-> I set my model to ignore null value and my app working perfectly fine

Thanks for your reply

Answer (score 3):

This Grey Screen indicate that you getting null value somewhere.

```
flutter run --release
```

You can check where you getting null value using above command.

Comment: but I have to send build in debug mode

Comment: Ya, Just check what is issue once you have fixed it send build in debug mode

Comment: there is some api issue so data receive null